# How to change value in Plist coco2dx c++?

Tags: c++, ios, cocos2d-x

Hi I am wondering how to change the value in a plist file that Ive created. Currently I can save a value in a plist that I made in code with this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=865TkhvlkUU but then I can't access what I saved outside the game (Is it possible to open files in writeable folder with text editor?). Also can I find answers to questions like this in the cocos2dx api? If so how do i navigate it to get information on plists. Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by `outside the game` ?

Comment: Meaning I cant actually access the plist file with text editor or anything like that. I have the idea of copying everything from a plist i made to one in the writable folder then changing and using those in game but then I don't know how to create nested directories and things will get very messy fast.

Answer (score -1):

You can easily change value in plist file, if you are using xcode then you can directly view and edit plist value. Also on windows system you can edit on notepad++ or something equivalent.

Tell me if you face any issue?